# Div should be centered but it's not?

Tags: html, css

Everything looks fine in both the HTML & CSS, so the div in question should be centered on the page. I have included some code snippets below, but the real code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/stbx08mk/

test-div at the bottom should be centered in the 1024 area, but it isn't. Why not?

```
#page-wrapper {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1024px;
}

#test-div {
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, you need to adjust your `#test-div` style to `float: none;` and `clear: both;`

```
#test-div {
  background-color: orange;
  clear: both;
  float: none;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
}
```

**[Your JSFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/stbx08mk/2/)**

Comment: This appears to be the most efficient solution. It's surprising that the div will still be positioned even though the float has been turned off. Works though so I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `#test-div` is not centered, is because you're using the property `float: left;` on it in your CSS. The auto margins don't work on floated elements.

Try removing the `float: left;` property to get your desired result.

Comment: Your answer may be more helpful with why that is the problem and how to change it to get the desired solution.

Answer (score 1):

**floating divs to center "works" with the combination of display:inline-block and text-align:center.**

First, remove the float attribute on the inner divs. Then, `Text-align:center` on the main outer div. And for the inner divs, `display:inline-block`.

Just tested it - `display:inline-block` on the inner divs works. Might also be wise to give them explicit widths too.

**For your problem**

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/stbx08mk/3/)

Remove `float:left;` and add `clear:both;` to `#test-div`.

It just worked for me..

This will solve your problem

Try it..

Answer (score 0):

Float: left is whats making it ignore your margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `<html>` and `<body>` tags take up the entire width of the browser and the margin and padding are both 0. This caused my content to be almost centered, but a little bit offset from center. Use this CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

In addition, in your `#test-div` use:

```
#test-div{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```